# Energy in simulated annealing algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, simulated-annealing

Am I correct in saying the energy in the simulated annealing algorithm is equal to the change in cost?

So I can calculate it with the follow:

```
energy = cost(prevSolution) - cost(currentSolution);
```

Comment: Does it really matter? They call it "Energy" because SA came from a thermodynamics analogy.

Answer (score 2):

The term 'energy' can have various definitions, but it usually means the current objective value, or the cost of the current state, that is `cost(currentSolution)`.

The difference you defined, along with some transition function, usually specifies the [transition probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing#Acceptance_probabilities) from one state to another.